# loop over loc shift(-i) and repalce q(i) columns to np.nan [pandas]

Tags: pandas

how do I loop this in pandas instaed of writning  44 times?

```
df.loc[(df['id']!=df['id'].shift(-1)),['q1']]=np.nan
df.loc[(df['id']!=df['id'].shift(-2)),['q2']]=np.nan
df.loc[(df['id']!=df['id'].shift(-3)),['q3']]=np.nan
```

Comment: using a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a for loop, which will substitute in a new value for i each time. I've done it up to 3 (as per your example), but from you question, I think this should go to 44.

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    df.loc[(df['id']!=df['id'].shift(-i)),['q' + str(i)]]=np.nan
```